# Setting __m256i to the value of two __m128i values

Tags: c, sse, simd, avx

So, AVX has a function from `immintrin.h`, which should allow to store the concatenation of two `__m128i` values into a single `__m256i` value. The function is

```
__m256i _mm256_set_m128i (__m128i hi, __m128i lo)
```

However, when I use it, like so:

```
__m256i as[2]; __m128i s[4]; as[0] = _mm256_setr_m128i(s[0], s[1]);
```

I get a compilation error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__m256i’ from type ‘int’
```

I don't really understand why this happens. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that function is in that header? When I try to use the function as you have after `#include <immintrin.h>`, I get the warning message "implicit declaration of `_mm256_set_m128i`". In C, an implicit declaration means that the compiler assumes the function will return an `int`, which would explain the compiler error as well.

Answer (score 12):

Not all compilers seem to have `_mm256_setr_m128i`, or even `_mm256_set_m128i`, defined in `immintrin.h`. So I usually just define macros as needed, bracketed with suitable `#ifdef`s which test for compiler and version:

```
#define _mm256_set_m128i(v0, v1)  _mm256_insertf128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(v1), (v0), 1)

#define _mm256_setr_m128i(v0, v1) _mm256_set_m128i((v1), (v0))
```

- Intel ICC 11.1 and later has both `_mm256_set_m128i` and `_mm256_setr_m128i`.
- MSVC 2012 and later has just `_mm256_set_m128i`.
- gcc/clang don't seem to have either, although I haven't checked recent versions to see if this has been fixed yet.

Comment: GCC appears to not even have `_mm256_set_m128i` in that header... [Link](http://ideone.com/f3gVol)

Comment: The thing is... I really care about performance here, so I wanna use the correct instruction, not just obtain something which is functionally the same

Comment: @MartinLauridsen: `_mm256_insertf128_si256` maps to a single instruction, so I don't think you can improve on this.

Comment: @PaulR, it seems I am having the same issues with the `_mm256_blend_epi16` instruction. Any ideas how to deal with that one?

Comment: @MartinLauridsen: `_mm256_blend_epi16` is AVX2 - are you compiling with `-mavx2` or equivalent ?

Comment: GCC seems to lack a lot of the "composite" intrinsics. I recently found that `_mm256_loadu2_m128` and family was the best way to do transposes from memory since (on ICC) it compiles to two instructions that don't use the vector shuffle port. On GCC, inline assembly is the only way to get the same effect. For AVX512, GCC lacks all the reduction intrinsics.

Comment: @Mysticial: you mean `movups / vinsertf128`?  You can write it with `v=_mm_loadu_ps` and `_mm256_castps128_ps256(v)`, etc.  See https://goo.gl/QEGPUq: both versions are the same on icc13, and the same as what you get on gcc all the way back to gcc 4.4.  Also note that `VINSERTF128` from mem or reg on Sandybridge can only run on port5.  It's great on Haswell, though, where any vector port can do the insert part.  BTW, gcc, when tuning for Sandybridge, splits unaligned 32B loads into two 16B loads with `vinsertf128`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options.

Comment: @PeterCordes So the problem with that macro on GCC is that if you compile without optimizations (as is the case with debugging), GCC will not embed the load and will use an aligned load. In a lot of cases (especially involving AOS <-> SOA transpositions), the data is actually misaligned in the AOS format in memory. So that crashes. Then if I use `_mm_loadu_ps()` for the upper half, GCC refuses to fuse it as a memory operand to `vinsertf128`, thereby completely backfiring. A similar situation applies to the store version.

Comment: A work-around is to `#ifdef` by optimization level. But I prefer to stay clear of that route.

Comment: @Mysticial: hmm, ok I see the problem you're talking about.  You have to make sure all your memory references go through a `loadu`, or the compiler might do them with a `movaps` at `-O0`.  Solution: use gcc 4.9.2 or newer, then `loadu` does fold into vinsertf128.  Or for gcc 4.8: always use at least `-Og`: "optimize for debugging", and keep your code that will fault if compiled at `-O0`.  https://goo.gl/eBPD5a.  Note that clang has both the intrinsics in question, `_mm256_set_m128i` and `_mm256_loadu2_m128`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh that's neat! I was indeed testing with GCC 4.8. Thanks!

Comment: I just ran into this.  I wanted to `vbroadcastf128` a pshufb constant into both lanes of a ymm register.  But gcc6.3.1 is horrible at everything I tried.  Your macro is the best of a bad situation, compiling to `vmovdqa`+`vinserti128`.  (clang compiles to a 256b vector).  Other attempts with gcc: `const __m128 tmp = _mm_castsi128_ps(shufmask128);` `_mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_broadcast_ps(&tmp))` compiles to an FP 128b load of the constant, an FP 128b store to the stack, and then a `vinsertf128` from the just-stored copy.  Pointer-casting was even worse, if you can believe that.

Comment: AFAICT, the only thing that isn't bad for gcc is to just write out the constant twice in a `_mm256_set_epi8`, maybe with a CPP macro to make it suck less. :(  Or for a table of shuffle masks, a load+insert may be an acceptable price, but still obviously worse than a broadcast-load.

Comment: Pain, pain, pain. It is on gcc 8.1. It is not on gcc 7.3. See source code at https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/avxintrin.h  . _mm256_set_m128i is there.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem and used a macro to work around it.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__ 
#if __GNUC__ < 8
#define _mm256_set_m128i(xmm1, xmm2) _mm256_permute2f128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(xmm1), _mm256_castsi128_si256(xmm2), 2)
#define _mm256_set_m128f(xmm1, xmm2) _mm256_permute2f128_ps(_mm256_castps128_ps256(xmm1), _mm256_castps128_ps256(xmm2), 2)
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: `_mm256_insertf128_si256` is always at least as cheap as `_mm256_permute2f128_ps`, or at least the corresponding asm instructions are.  I didn't check how this compiles for constants vs. runtime variables.