# gcc chokes on _mm256_set_m128i intrinsic from AVX

Tags: gcc, intrinsics, avx

I use the [_mm256_set_m128i](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_set_m128i) intrinsic.

clang v6 is fine with it, but gcc 7.3.0 chokes on it, with:

```
implicit declaration of function ‘_mm256_set_m128i’; did you mean ‘_mm256_set_epi8’
```

I compile with **-mavx** and include **immintrin.h** header.

Code in question:

```
    __m128i lo = _mm256_extractf128_si256( value, 0 );
    lo = _mm_mullo_epi32( lo, PRIMSLO );
    __m128i hi = _mm256_extractf128_si256( value, 1 );
    hi = _mm_mullo_epi32( hi, PRIMSHI );
    const __m256i v = _mm256_set_m128i( hi, lo );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Setting __m256i to the value of two __m128i values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32630458/2439725).

Comment: It compiles with gcc 8. With gcc 7 use `_mm256_inserti128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(lo),hi,1);`. See [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/nRkVJX).

Comment: My previous comment works only with AVX2. With AVX it is `_mm256_insertf128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(lo),hi,1);` [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/Vi2rpR).